# Php, dependency injection, is it good to inject something just to hand on to an other object?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, factory

Here is my code:

```
abstract class Sql { }

class MySQL extends Sql { }

class OracleSQL extends Sql { }

class A
{
    public function doA(Sql $sql) { ... }
}

class B
{
    public function doB(Sql $sql) { ... }
}

class Users
{
    public function __construct(Sql $sql)
    {
        if (rand(0,1) == 0) // depends on the circumstances
        {
             $a = new A($sql);
             $a->doA();
        }
        else
        {
             $b = new B($sql);
             $b->doB();
        }
    }
}
```

there are a few problems with that:

- `A` and `B` is hardcoded, of course. But how to pass them if the `Users::constructor` decides which to use? Its unnecesarry to create both, just in case
- the `User` itself dont need to have instance of `A` or `B`, not even `Sql`

This problem seems like "passing an envelope to A to bring it to B but only B has the right to read it, still A may open that"

Comment: You already added the tag `factory` this might be the way to go here. That requires, that A and B have something in common, though. You would inject the factory then. Some frameworks use a service container for that sort of thing.